# Get newly added object in Material-ui Autocomplete component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, autocomplete, material-ui

I'm using [material-ui Autcomplete](https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/) component with `multiple` selection. And for one of the scenario, I need to get the value for newly added item. When I'm using `onChange` listener, it is giving me all the values selected in Autocomplete input. Is there any way to get only added or removed one?
Codesandbox - https://codesandbox.io/s/xqex8?file=/demo.js

Answer (score 1):

according to the doc, the onChange funct receive three properties, called `event`, `value`, and reason. You can receive the value of newly added item by taking advantage of `event.target.textContent` as below:

```
onChange={(event, value) =>
          console.log(
            top100Films.filter(
              (el, id) => el.title === event.target.textContent
            )
          )
        }
```

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-dkv05?file=/demo.js:680-862)

Comment: pls let me know if it solves your question

Comment: Thanks @ali. This has partially solved my problem. I'm able to get newly added element with this but still stuck with removed one.